# How to set the db information which is automatically generated in container's environmental variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I want to pass the necesarry information(ALB url,Bucket name and DATABASE info) to the ECS container via environmental variable.

```
const djangoContainer = adminTaskDefinition.addContainer('adminContainer', {
  image: djangoImage,
  memoryReservationMiB:700,
  environment:{
  INTERNAL_ALB:String(props?.internalLoadBalancer.loadBalancerDnsName),
    ADMIN_BUCKET:String(props?.adminBucket.bucketName),
    DBNAME:props!.dbSecret!.secretValue.toJSON().dbname
    //I want to put DBPASSWORD: DBHOST: and so on
  },
```

I made `ALB` and `Bucket` and `RDS` in another stack and pass the each references to `addContainer`

When I executed this code,`INTERNAL_ALB` and `ADMIN_BUCKET` is correctly set in environmental variable in container, but  there is no `DBNAME`.

My idea is wrong?(pass the Secret Manager's information to environemntal variable is bad idea?)

This secret code is automatically made like this below.

```
const rdsCredentials: rds.Credentials = rds.Credentials.fromGeneratedSecret("myuser" ,{secretName:'secret-name`});
const instance = new rds.DatabaseInstance(this, "PostgresInstance1", {
  credentials: rdsCredentials,
  engine: rds.DatabaseInstanceEngine.POSTGRES,
  vpc:vpc,
  instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.BURSTABLE4_GRAVITON,ec2.InstanceSize.MICRO),
  instanceIdentifier: metaInfo['databaseIdentifier'],
  databaseName : metaInfo['databaseName'],
  vpcSubnets: vpc.selectSubnets({ subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC }),
  securityGroups:[dbSecurityGroup],
  allocatedStorage:20,
});

this.dbSecret = instance.secret;
```

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 1):

`SecretValue.toJSON()` does not return the actual secret value, so you cannot manipulate it directly.

You need [`Secret.secretValueFromJSON()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_secretsmanager.Secret.html#secretwbrvaluewbrfromwbrjsonjsonfield):

```
DBNAME:props!.dbSecret!.secretValueFromJson("dbname")
```